# How to center y label on stacked subplots in Julia's Makie?

Tags: plot, julia

Here is some example plotting code:

```
using Makie

fig = Figure(resolution = (2400, 2000), backgroundcolor = RGBf0(0.98, 0.98, 0.98), fontsize = 48)

ax1 = fig[1, 1] = Axis(fig, title = "Title")
x = LinRange(0,20,100)

lines!(ax1, x, sin)
    
ax2 = fig[2, 1] = Axis(fig)

lines!(ax2, x, cos)
linkaxes!(ax1, ax2)
ax2.ylabel = "I want my label centered, but how?"
current_figure()
```

This makes the following plot:
[image: demo plot]

As you can see, the ylabel is on axis 2. This is not surprising since that's what I told it to do. I have looked in the documentation pretty thoroughly (which is quite good) and I don't see an obvious way to make the ylabel be centered on the two axes. I thought about trying to make a figure with a bounding box surrounding this one and removing everything except the ylabel, but I wasn't sure how and that seems like way too much of a hack for what should be a reasonably common thing to do.

So, how do I get my ylabel to be centered on the two plots?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the `Labels` layoutable.

For instance,

```
using Makie

fig = Figure(resolution = (2400, 2000), backgroundcolor = RGBf0(0.98, 0.98, 0.98), fontsize = 48)

ax1 = fig[1, 1] = Axis(fig, title = "Title")
x = LinRange(0,20,100)

lines!(ax1, x, sin)
    
ax2 = fig[2, 1] = Axis(fig)

lines!(ax2, x, cos)
linkaxes!(ax1, ax2)
ax2.ylabel = "I want my label centered, but how?"
ylabel = Label(fig[1:2, 0], "Now the label is centered!", rotation = pi/2)
current_figure()
```

Notice, you need to pass the rotation in order for the text draw vertically. One can also provide any range to center based on those subplots.